# Kleisli in Cats for Scala example not working

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Im trying out the [following](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/composing-monadic-functions.html) example in a Scala worksheet:

```
import cats._, cats.data._, cats.implicits._
val f = Kleisli { (x: Int) => (x + 1).some }
val g = Kleisli { (x: Int) => (x * 100).some }
```

However it does not type check, the error im getting is on row 2 and 3.

> Expression of type Option[Int] dosent conform to expected type F_[B_]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does typecheck. What you're seeing is probably your IDEs Scala compiler (I'm assuming you're seeing this in IDEA) not being able to infer the type, but if you compile this with SBT or in the Scala REPL, it works:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

val f = Kleisli { (x: Int) => (x + 1).some }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
f: cats.data.Kleisli[Option,Int,Int] = Kleisli(<function1>)
```

And the worksheet, you can see the highlight error, but the code compiles (IntelliJ 2017.1.2 Ultimate):

[image: Klesli Scala Worksheet]

I've also [opened an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11912) in IntelliJ IDEA issue tracker.

Comment: Is this something that is fixable in the Scala plugin or will it probably always be like this?

Comment: @user3139545 It's fixable. I've [opened an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11912)